# Chaotic Animation: Legion summoned by Prince Mudeenu

Tags: plot-explanation, chaotic

In the 10th episode of the first season of 2006 Animation Chaotic , "Castle Bodhran or Bust (Part Two)", starting at 10:40. Prince Mudeenu, Captain of the Mipedian Guard and nephew of the king, tells Zhade he will summon a specific legion as reinforcement to the upcoming battle.

Well... That's precisely what I would like to know: The proper way to write the name of this legion would be very helpful for the subtitles I'm creating for the show.

I can understand what he says, "Legion of Catah", but I'm not sure if this "Catah" spells like I this. Especially because Mipedian names usually have apostrophes or non-standard letters for some words.

And I couldn't find information about it anywhere

Comment: According to an online transcript (from Ark TV, which I *think* are official closed captions but not 100% sure), it's **Khatal**.

Comment: Would it be possible to provide the source of this transcripts? It would be amazingly helpful to finish all the task sooner.

Comment: Sure, it's [here](http://tv.ark.com/transcript/chaotic-%28castle_bodhran_or_bust__part_ii%29/4794/DXDP/Thursday_May_13_2010/295322/).